# Sharepoint 2013 site not opening in sharepoint designer 2013

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer

The site which I was working was opening in SharePoint designer 2013. But since yesterday, it has stopped opening in designer 2013. Why would this happen so. `I have enabled all the settings in "SharePoint Designer Settings" under "Site Administration" of site.` Also the settings at the web application level are enabled. I also uninstalled the sharepoint designer 2013, and re-installed it again. Yet any of the sites in my web application list are failing to open in designer. Why do that happen so. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Are you receiving an error? Can you please attach a screen print

Comment: No I didn't receive any error. I go to the designer then on sites page when I click on any of the site link. It does not open.

Comment: It could be a designer cache issue as well, try deleting it. Also check out the page and open itg in advanvce mode directly.

Comment: I cleared the browser cache. But still not working. Which page I need to check out and how to open in the advanced mode?

Comment: not browser cache, SharePoint designer cache!

Comment: Yeah yeah sorry I cleared designer cache but still it is not working.

Comment: you should then try to reinstall it or try a different machine.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue a couple of weeks ago, but it disappeared when I tried to reinstall SPD again and ran the repair option.

Comment: I tried doing the same uninstalling the sharepoint designer 2013 and then again installing it. But still it is not opening any site.

Comment: But when I try opening it using open site option on designer 2013, it is giving me an error, "The web server at "Website" does appear to have microsoft sharepoint foundation install".

Answer (score 0):

Try investigating the issue using Fiddler. You should be able to see if the designer is issuing requests to the sharepoint site and what response you are getting from the server.

Comment: It is not giving me any error as such.